# OpenVPN client site network routing

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I have the following openvpn setup, the goal is to make host D can connect to any of the computer(linux) in the corporate network to do some maintaining job:

```
        corporate network                           remote vpn server
=============================================      =====================
    A                B          C(vpn client)      D(vpn server)
10.0.10.101 ---- 10.0.10.100                   |
                 10.0.51.100 ---- 10.0.51.101  |
                                  10.8.1.2  ---|-- 10.8.1.1
                                               |
```

host B route table:

```
10.8.1.0/24 via 10.0.51.101
```

host C route table:

```
10.0.10.0/24 via 10.0.51.100
```

host D route table:

```
10.0.10.0/24 via 10.8.1.2
10.0.51.0/24 via 10.8.1.2
```

The openvpn is being setup with subnet topology, which links corporate network subnet 10.0.51.0/24.

My purpose is to make host D can link with host A, here is the progress I made:

1. B ping through D(10.8.1.1): OK
2. D ping through B(10.0.10.100): Failed
3. D ping through B(10.0.51.100): OK
4. B ping C 10.0.51.101/10.8.1.2: OK
5. C ping B(10.0.10.100/10.0.51.100): OK

It seems that route 10.0.10./24 via 10.8.1.2 being ignored when doing traceroute. How can I setup to make the host D on subnet 10.0.51.0/24 link to 10.0.10.0/24?

Comment: Are you using OpenVPN in tun or tap mode?

Comment: It's in tun mode

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN's *tun* interfaces are layer 3 only – they do not use anything like MAC addresses, and packets sent through them do not have a layer-2 header.

This means that the kernel actually has no way to select which gateway to use when sending packets over a tun interface, and all your `via 10.8.1.x` routes just act like they were `dev tun0` routes.

To solve this, the VPN server software *itself* (i.e. the receiving end of the tun interface) needs to have its own internal routing table mapping destination addresses to clients, and in OpenVPN this is called "iroute".

1. You need to use `client-config-dir` on server D to be able to specify per-client configuration (as OpenVPN decided to make iroutes client-based, without the ability to specify a gateway IP).
2. In the server's per-client config file for host C, add the options `iroute 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0` and `iroute 10.0.51.0 255.255.255.0`.

The same applies to all layer-3 VPNs. (For example, WireGuard uses `AllowedIPs=` to route destinations to different clients on the same interface.)

Comment: It works like this:  the operating system's routing will get the traffic *to* the OpenVPN gateway.  But it knows nothing of how the various OpenVPN clients are configured.  `iroute` then tells OpenVPN *which* remote client to send the traffic to for its "next hop."